# How do I copy pictures onto a folder on the home screen?

Tags: home-screen

I have some pictures that I want to copy to a folder on the home screen, but I can't see any way to do that.  The home screen isn't a directory like all the others, so I can't *copy* files there.  Is there any way to do that?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S with Froyo.

Comment: The only things you can add to folders on the home screen are app shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install a file manager app like [Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro) you can put any files into any directory you create, including pictures.  Then all you have to do is make a shortcut to that directory on the home screen.

Comment: I can already put any files into any directory without a special file manager app.  The question is, how do I make a shortcut to a directory on the home screen?

Comment: Just like I said in the answer, the app adds the shortcut action to the shortcut context menu.

Comment: gotcha! accepted!

Answer (score 4):

I know an answer has already been accepted but I just wanted to add that you can also use [ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) (I am not the developer I just know some prefer it to Astro) however you must download the [ES Bookmark Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop.app.shortcut) in order for it to work.

In order to create the shortcut just long-click on a folder from within the app and select "Shortcut" from the context menu.  A shortcut to that folder will appear on your home screen.  If you don't already have the "Bookmark Manager" installed it will prompt you to download it from the Market

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The [File Jump](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.FreshBlood.FileJump) app provides the functionality to create shortcuts to files directly. You can create home-screen shortcuts to your images and then drag them into home-screen folders - just an option!