# How can I put a link to an SD card folder on the home screen on HTC Desire Z?

Tags: home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts, link2sd, file-management

I have a folder on  my SD card that I regularly access to open documents of different types.

Is it possible to have a link on the home screen that opens the contents of this folder, e.g. using a File Manager application?

Currently I'm using the Adao File Manager to open the folder, but every time I have to select SD Card and Folder to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to [How do I copy pictures onto a folder on the home screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/how-do-i-copy-pictures-onto-a-folder-on-the-home-screen) provide a couple methods of creating shortcuts (it requires another file manager).

As well, the Root Explorer file manager allows you to set the default path when it opens; you could set it to the path of this folder, so you wouldn't need to browse to it.